# freeglut: failed to open display '', linux subsystem

Tags: c, opengl, debian, windows-subsystem-for-linux, freeglut

Im trying to run this simple hello world program with openGL and C.
Im running this in a debian subsystem on windows and i think that is part of the problem.

**Main.c**:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<GL/glut.h>
void displayMe(void)
{
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
        glVertex3f(0.5, 0.0, 0.5);
        glVertex3f(0.5, 0.0, 0.0);
        glVertex3f(0.0, 0.5, 0.0);
        glVertex3f(0.0, 0.0, 0.5);
        glEnd();
        glFlush();
}
int main(int argc, char** argv){
        glutInit(&argc, argv);
        glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE);
        glutInitWindowSize(400, 300);
        glutInitWindowPosition(100, 100);
        glutCreateWindow("Hello world!");
        glutDisplayFunc(displayMe);
        glutMainLoop();
        return 0;
}
```

but i get this error:

```
freeglut (./firstOpenGlApp): failed to open display ''
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's looking for an X server. The DISPLAY var would normally be exported to ":0", however, given that this is on Windows, I doubt there is one available.

If `xterm -display :0` does not work, you may be better off installing VirtualBox, and install a proper Linux distro within it.

Comment: `xterm` did not seam to work, but ill try a virtualmachine!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try installing Xlanch, my wsl2 ubuntu worked after following this instructions: https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4106

Comment: Consider explaining why Xlanch would help to solve this specific problem. This answer is a link only answer without an explanation.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31106351)